# Issue with setState in React and React-Draggable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap

I am having difficulties with the setState function in react. I am using the react-draggable package and I can drag my div around but it doesn't appear to be setting the x y coordinates when I release the mouse button, so the div just snaps back to where it was. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here with the onControlledDrag? Thanks!

```
  export class DraggableAnswer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.controlledPosition ={ x: -25, y: 10};
  }
  onControlledDrag(e, position) {
    console.log(position);
    const {x, y} = position;
    this.setState({
      controlledPosition: {x: x, y: y}
    });
  }


  render() {
    const dragHandlers = {onStart: this.onStart, onStop: this.onStop};    

    return (
      <div className="draggableAnswerBlock">
            <Draggable
              zIndex={100}
              position={this.controlledPosition}
              {...dragHandlers}
              onDrag={this.onControlledDrag.bind(this)}>
                <div className="box">
                  Change my position
                </div>
            </Draggable>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the constructor it should be:

```
constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);

  this.state = { controlledPosition: { x: -25, y: 10} };
}
```

and then in the return you should pass this.state.controlledPosition into Draggable. Right now this.controlledPosition never updates so it will reset when the drag is done.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really clarifies for me how the whole this.state and setState relationship works!